# pandas - map dataframe element with dictionary - how to access nth element of value list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

suppose I have a dataframe called df

```
d = {'country_code':['SP','FR','US']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

next to that I have the following dictionary. Note that each key has a list of values instead of one value

```
dictionary = {'SP': ['Spain','Europe'],'IT':['Italy','Europe']}
```

I know I can use the map function to map the dictionary values in my dataframe:

```
df['zone'] = df['country_code'].map(dictionary)
```

However I would only like to map the second element of the value list instead of the complete list. So for 'SP' in the dataframe I should get 'Europe' and not ['Spain','Europe']. I assumed the syntaxis would be

```
df['zone'] = df['country_code'].map(dictionary)[1]
```

but that's not the case

Can somebody help?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str) accessor for a *hacky* solution:

```
df['zone'] = df['country_code'].map(dictionary).str[1]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  country_code    zone
0           SP  Europe
1           FR     NaN
2           US     NaN
```

A more clean alternative is just to create a new dictionary from the existing one:

```
df['zone'] = df['country_code'].map({k : vs[1] for k, vs in dictionary.items()})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  country_code    zone
0           SP  Europe
1           FR     NaN
2           US     NaN
```